# How to get past error Bad value for ai_flags in Lambda function

Tags: c#, asynchronous, aws-lambda, async-await

I've following code for asynchronously copying files within S3 bucket. A large chunk batch is broken down into smaller batches and handed over to methods/functions. A list of functions is created (depending on the size of large batch) and run accordingly. This is a AWS Lambda function.

**Code**:

```
public async Task CreateAndExecuteSpawnAsync(string srcBucket, List<List<string>> pdfFileList, IAmazonS3 s3client)
{
    int i = 0;
    List<Func<Task>> actions = new List<Func<Task>>();
    LambdaLogger.Log("PDF Set count: " + pdfFileList.Count.ToString());
    foreach (var list in pdfFileList)
        actions.Add(() => RenameFilesAsync(srcBucket, list, s3client));

    foreach (var method in actions)
    {
        await method();
        LambdaLogger.Log("Mehtod invoked: "+ i++.ToString());
    }
}
            
public async Task RenameFilesAsync(string srcBucket, List<string> pdfFiles, IAmazonS3 s3client)
{
LambdaLogger.Log("In RenameFileAsync method");
CopyObjectRequest copyRequest = new CopyObjectRequest
{
    SourceBucket = srcBucket,
    DestinationBucket = srcBucket
};
try
{
  var tasks = pdfFiles
      .Where(file => !file.Contains("index.xml"))
      .Select(async file =>
      {
         string[] newFilename = file.Split('{');
         string[] destKey = file.Split('/');
         copyRequest.SourceKey = file;
         copyRequest.DestinationKey = destKey[0] + "/" + destKey[1] + "/Renamed/" + newFilename[1];
         LambdaLogger.Log("About to rename File: " + file);
         CopyObjectResponse response = await s3client.CopyObjectAsync(copyRequest);
         LambdaLogger.Log("Rename done: ");
      })
      .ToList();
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
}
```

**Error:**

```
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
at Amazon.Runtime.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponseAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)   
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RedirectHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ResponseHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ExceptionHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at AWSLambda3.Function.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<<RenameFilesAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\ajagdale2\source\repos\AWSLambda3\Function.cs:line 151
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   
at AWSLambda3.Function.RenameFilesAsync(String srcBucket, List`1 pdfFiles, IAmazonS3 s3client) in C:\Users\ajagdale2\source\repos\AWSLambda3\Function.cs:line 155
```

**Basically the error is generated from this line:**

```
CopyObjectResponse response = await s3client.CopyObjectAsync(copyRequest);
```

Comment: Can you do connect with AWS with other parts of your code.  You are failing an http connection.  There could be lots of reasons for the failure.  Do you have latest version of AWS installed?  The connection uses https (secure) with TLS authentication and your version of TLS being used may be obsolete.  Are you getting any response. If you are not getting a response then issue is usually TLS.  If you are getting a response with an error code than you may not be using a valid id and need to register with AWS for an ID.

Comment: @jdweng Sorry, that I didn't give the complete information. Like I mentioned and if you notice in my code 'await.metnod()' is run from foreach. Error is realised only in first batch or in first time loop runs but since the error is handled, loops carries on and all other file are processed successfully.

Comment: The error message in the title isn't anywhere in the question...

Comment: It looks like from exception you r trying to rename a file (RenameFilesAsync).  Is the file still open?

Comment: @jdweng Well, why the file should be open, it's just a copy operation? Even I had a thought of it and at some point I did get message 'Too many files open' but I didn't find a way to close the open file.

Comment: Try adding a long wait after the copy operations.  Not sure if the await is really waiting.

Comment: @jdweng did try that too but it didn't work

Comment: Is a file in the list twice?

Comment: No, there is only one file. I fail to understand that this happens only to the first batch of files, rest others get processed successfully. Each batch contains 6k files.